# Toggle animation on click of button using js

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm trying to get a square to 'fold out' on click of a button -- kind of like a drop-down.

Right now I have this, but it doesn't seem to do anything...

```js
function toggle() {
  let classList = document.getElementById('box').classList;
  
  if (classList.contains('expand')) {
    classList.remove('expand');
    classList.add('retract');
  } else if (classList.contains('retract')) {
    classList.remove('retract');
    classList.add('expand');
  }
}
```

```css
@keyframes anim {
  0%: {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  1%: {
    visibility: visible;
    max-height: 0px; 
  }
  100%: {
    visibility: visible;
    max-height: 100px; /* or something bigger than we'll 'ever need' */
  }
}

.expand .retract {
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-iteration-count: 1; 
}

.expand {
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.retract {
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

#box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">toggle</button>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Note, that I need to have `visibility: hidden` here!

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think the problem is that `div` is neither of `.expand` class, nor `.retract` class at the very beginning, so neither condition is met, hence nothing happens.

Comment: @doli, could you explain why you need to have `visibility: hidden` on the element when it's neither animating nor open? `height: 0; overflow: hidden` already achieves that (which is: the element is not visible). If it's visible while closed, you might want to remove any top-margin from its first child or bottom margin from its last child. That should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, your problem is solved. [This tryit](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition2) from W3Schools helped me a lot. I didn't need two class names. Also, as @tao said, there is no point in animating `visibility` (look at the comments below). [Here](https://codepen.io/loglinn05/pen/GRBLpNp) is the CodePen pen with this code. I guess this is what you want, am I right?

```js
const toggle = () => box?.classList.toggle('expand')
```

```css
#box.expand {
  height: 100px;
}

#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
  transition: height 1s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">toggle</button>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) has a `toggle()` method. Which means `toggle()` function could be written as: `const toggle = () => document.getElementById('box')?.classList.toggle('expand')`

Comment: Also, there's no point in animating `visibility`, because it's not animatable. Only properties accepting number-based values are animatable, as they can transition from one value to another through intermediary values, according to a timing-function. There's no way for a browser to animate between `visible` and `hidden` values. If it did, what would we expect halfway through the animation? `hidible`/`visiden`? The change of value can only be instantaneous.

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/5hjscnez/)'s a cleaned-up version of your answer.

Comment: @tao, OP wanted to have `visibility: hidden`, he said this at the end of the post, and I didn't know it's not animatable. Also, thank you for cleaning up my answer. I'll edit it.

Comment: Well, instead of copy/pasting code that's ***never*** going to do anything, I suggest you remove it from your answer and explain why it's useless.